# How to find wather SharePoint Foundation 2010 Sp1 and CU June 2011 are installed in the windows 2008 server R2

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to find out weather SharePoint 2010 Sp1 and CUJune 2011 are installed in the windows 2008 server R2?

Comment: SharePoint2010 version 14.0.4762, SharePoint 2010 SP1 version 14.0.6029, we can also find the same in Registry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to CA or Powershell and get the build version.

Get-SPFarm | Select BuildVersion